# Shiny-error while trying to use tableoutput

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a basic shiny code which gives an error while I am trying to show tableoutput but same dataframe gets printed when I change line to renderprint, I can download the file using download handler which shows there are records there.
  **"Warning: Error in <-: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"**
My dataset and code is below.

```
structure(list(Point1 = c(9999, 9999, 433.333, 9999, 1433.333, 
33.333, 4283.333, 9999, 33.333, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 0.033, 
1323.333, 883.333, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 433.333, 1433.333, 
0.633, 9999, 9999, 9999, 33.333, 9999, 133.333, 433.333, 433.333, 
0.003, 4023.333, 33.333, 423.333, 1323.333, 423.333, 1323.333, 
4323.333, 2073.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 
33.333, 123.333, 3363.333, 123.333, 0.333, 423.333), Point2 = c(4433.333, 
4433.333, 133.333, 4133.333, 433.333, 3.333, 1283.333, 4433.333, 
3.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 0.003, 423.333, 
433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 133.333, 433.333, 
0.333, 4358.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 3.333, 4433.333, 33.333, 
133.333, 133.333, NA, 1323.333, 3.333, 123.333, 423.333, 123.333, 
423.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 423.333, 423.333, 423.333, 423.333, 
423.333, 3.333, 33.333, 1323.333, 33.333, 0.033, 123.333), OUTP1 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), Types = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Point1", "Point2", 
"OUTP1", "Types"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L
))


    library(survival)
    library(shiny)
           ui <- bootstrapPage(
           titlePanel("Title comes here"),
           tags$hr(),
           sidebarPanel(
           fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
           multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
            "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
            ".csv")),
         tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

        radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                     choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                 Semicolon = ";",
                                 Tab = "\t"),
                     selected = ","),

        radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                     choices = c(None = "",
                                 "Double Quote" = '"',
                                 "Single Quote" = "'"),
                     selected = '"'),

        tags$hr(),

        radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                     choices = c(Head = "head",
                                 All = "all"),
                     selected = "head"),

        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        # plotOutput('plot'),
        tableOutput("selected_var")
    )
    )
     server <- function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)

        test1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                                header = input$header,
                                sep = input$sep,
                                quote = input$quote)
        test1[is.na(test1)] <- "0"

        return(list(df = test1))
    })
    output$selected_var <- renderTable(data()$df)
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
`
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what the problem is.  It sounds like you want to use `renderprint` somewhere but that doesn't work; is that right?  Can you post an example with `renderprint` in the place where you want to use it?  Why is it important to use `renderprint` for your project?  Also, is the table provided by `structure` important for the example?  It doesn't seem to actually do anything in the code.

Comment: As i explained already renderprint works and shows the data in dataframe, but i need to show output in tabularformat which throws this error.